# Expecting custom exception instead of null pointer exception while junit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, nullpointerexception, mockito

I have method in java class :

```
@Context
UriInfo uriInfo;
public void processRequest(@QueryParam ("userId") @DefaultValue("") String userId)
{
     String baseURI = uriInfo.getBaseUri().toString();
     if(userId == null)
     {
         //UserIdNotFoundException is my custom exception which extends Exceptition
         throw new UserIdNotFoundException();
     }
 }
```

When I'm junit testing the above method expecting for UserIdNotFoundException when userId parameter is Null, I get the following Assertion error : `expected  an instance of UserIdNotFoundException but <java.lang.NullPointerException> is java.lang.NullPointerException`.

```
@Test
public void testProcessRequest_throws_UserIdNotFoundException()
{
     expectedException.expect(UserIdNotFoundException.class);
     processRequest(null);
}
```

My custom exception class :

```
public class UserIdNotFoundException extends Exception
{

     public UserIdNotFoundException()
     {

     }

     public UserIdNotFoundException(String message)
     {
          super(message);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the annotation:

```
@Test(expected = UserIdNotFoundException.class)
public void testProcessRequest_throws_UserIdNotFoundException() {
     processRequest(null);
}
```

The problem might be that your `processRequest` implementation might be hitting the NPE before you have a chance to check for user id.

This is a good thing: Your test shows that the implementation does not meet your requirement.  You can fix it forever now.

This is what TDD is good for.

Comment: How can I my implementation be hitting null pointer exception before my check. I not calling any of string methods on userId. Or I'm not getting your point. Also I'm taking userId as Query Param from the Url. Only possibilty is that it might be involving some null check.

Comment: You'd have to post the implementation for processRequest for me to spell that out for you.  A better, more educational idea might be to step through the process in a debugger.  Put a breakpoint at the first line in processRequest and see how the observed behavior is not matching your expectations.

Comment: I debugged it as you suggested. The error was shown on the line uriInfo.getBaseUri().toString() it seems.So I put that line after the if check. The test shows green bar now. But I still didn't get the reason.

Comment: I still didn't understood why it was hitting NPE when using uriInfo

Comment: You still didn't post the implementation, so I can't help you.  You should be able to figure this out.

Comment: @Ashley might be `getBaseUri()` returning null and calling `toString()` on it throwing the `NullPointer`

Comment: @duffymo Yes the implementation was partly posted see the `String baseURI = uriInfo.getBaseUri().toString();` added in the method and the `uriInfo` varaible declare with `@Context`

Answer (score 0):

You have to write custom Exception class [this example](http://www.javatpoint.com/custom-exception) might help you.

**sample code:**

```
class UserIdNotFoundException extends Exception{  
 UserIdNotFoundException  (String s){  
  super(s);  
 }  
}
```

**Test Exception:**

```
 public void processRequest(String userId)
{
     if(userId == null)
     {
         //UserIdNotFoundException is my custom exception which extends Exception
         throw new UserIdNotFoundException("SOME MESSAGE");
     }
 }
```

remove default constructor from your exception class, JVM implicitly create it for you/

Comment: I have written my custom exception class but still I'm getting same assertion error.

Comment: Updated answer, try it.

Comment: How will removing the constructor solve the above problem?

Comment: I'm not telling it ll fix the issue, but its not require.

Comment: Not a good example of how to extend Exception.  There's only one constructor; I'd recommend overriding all four of them.

Comment: @duffymo, most of people create one constructor. let us know any specific  reason to override four

Comment: "Most people" - no data supporting that.  When I extend Exception, I ask IntelliJ to override all the constructors.  It's easy.  No reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not set `uriInfo` with a value and you're calling a method on a null value. Are you sure you're test is setup to give a value to `uriInfo` ? Or `getBaseUri()` might be returning `null` and calling `toString()` on it might throw the `NullPointerException`. This would be done by inspecting the return value of `getBaseUri()` in a debugger.

Normally you can either run your test with a config with beans for your test or you can add setter to set the value in your class of test to mock it or give a value in test. This should help avoid `NullPointerException`.

Either way you should always do the fail verification before doing any real work in a method.